# Integration of the reciprocal of sum exponential

Tags: integration

Any one know the method to do the integration as

$$\int\frac{x^2\cdot \exp (-ax^2) \exp(-bx^2)}{\exp(-ax^2)+\exp(-bx^2)}dx$$

It can be simplified as

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\exp(ax^2)+\exp(bx^2)}dx$$

But, I don't know how to further solve the problem, can anyone give me some advices or recommend some references?

Comment: Are you sure this *can* be done in elementary functions?

Comment: Note that you can also scale $x$ so that $|a|=1$. Mathematica gives the integral in terms of a hypergeometric function, and I doubt it has elementary form. If $a=1$ and $b\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2,3\}$, the integral is an elementary function.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Are you sure about that?  Wolfram Alpha gave me "no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions", nor could Maple get a closed-form solution, either for general $b$ or for most of the the special cases you mentioned.  For $a=b$, the solution involves **erf**, which is not an elementary function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I don't remember exactly, but I may have made a typo in the integrand. Anyway the main conclusion seems to remain: apart from possibly some special cases, there is no solution in elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|>|b|$ (otherwise swap the two variables)
$$
\int \frac{x^2}{\exp(ax^2)+\exp(bx^2)}dx=
\int \frac{x^2}{e^{ax^2}[1+e^{(b-a)x^2}]}dx
=\int \frac{x^2}{e^{ax^2}[1+e^{-(a-b)x^2}]}dx
=
\int \frac{x^2e^{-ax^2}}{1+e^{-(a-b)x^2}}dx
$$
$$
=
\sum_{k\ge 0}(-)^k\int x^2e^{-ax^2} e^{-k(a-b)x^2}dx
=
\sum_{k\ge 0}(-)^k\int x^2e^{-[(k+1)a-b]x^2} dx
$$
and with $t\equiv (k+1)a-b$
$$
=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-)^k\int x^2e^{-tx^2} dx
=\sum_{k\ge 0} (-)^k \left[-\frac{x}{2t}e^{-tx^2}+\frac{\surd \pi}{4t^{3/2}}\mathrm{erf}(x\surd t)\right]
$$